# Unable to compare multiple array values with dynamic array in expect-Protractor

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

Below is the scenario i am trying to automate:

I am getting an expectation failure  when comparing static array with a dynamic array.

Below is my code:

```
describe('My Test', function() {
    var names1="";
    var names2="";
    var names3="";
    it('Test starts', function() {

    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get('https://www.w3schools.com/angular/');

    browser.sleep(5000).then(function(){ 
    });
        var results = element.all(by.css(".sidesection>p>a"));
        results.get(0).getText().then(function(text){
            console.log("Names are "+text);
            names1=text;
        })
        results.get(1).getText().then(function(text){
            console.log("Names are "+text);
         names2=text;
        })
        results.get(2).getText().then(function(text){
            console.log("Names are "+text);
         names3=text;
        })

    }); 
    it('Test starts2', function() {
    var array=[names1,names2,names3];
    console.log("URLS fetched are this:- "+names1); 
    console.log("URLS fetched are this:- "+names2); 
    console.log("URLS fetched are this:- "+names3);
    var results2 = element.all(by.css(".sidesection>p>a"));
    expect(results2.getText()).toContain(array);   
    });

});
```

Comment: Output:

    Message:
    [31m    Expected [ 'Tabs', 'Dropdowns', 'Accordions', 'Convert Weights', 'Animated Buttons', 'Side Navigation', 'Top Navigation', 'JS Animations', 'Modal Boxes', 'Progress Bars', 'Parallax', 'Login Form', 'HTML Includes', 'Google Maps', 'Loaders', 'Tooltips', 'Slideshow', 'Filter List', 'Sort List' ] to contain [ 'Tabs', 'Dropdowns', 'Accordions' ].[0m
      Stack:
        Error: Failed expectation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also try to segreggate the array values in form of individual string keywords & then use them in the expect statements like below:

```
expect(results2.getText()).toContain(names1);   
expect(results2.getText()).toContain(names2);  
expect(results2.getText()).toContain(names3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are trying to `expect(someArray).toContain(array)` which is not possible. In case of **string or regex** it is possible. For you solution we can perform like this,

```
element.all(by.css(".sidesection>p>a")).getText().then(function(menus){
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        expect(menus.indexOf(array[i])!=-1).toBeTruthy(); 
    }
});
```